# MYSQL tables auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

When I copy all tables from one database and paste them to other database, how to set all auto_increments from these tables to start value? Is it possible to make a php script for such thing?

Comment: What do you mean by copying and pasting one database to another? I would use a dedicated Database Tool such as Sequel Pro or Toad to export my database then import it into the new one

Comment: `ALTER TABLE mytable AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000`. Where 1000 could be any start value.

Comment: When i copy all tables from one website and put them to another site I want all auto_increments to start from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
ALTER TABLE test AUTO_INCREMENT = 'startvalue'
```

**Condition**:
    if table not empty  start value must greater then MAX(AUTO_INCREMENT)

Answer (score 0):

If AUTO_INCREMENT column is primary key and if you re-sort the AUTO_INCREMENT column data, it may be problem in relationship with other tables. Instead of re-sorting your AUTO_INCREMENT data, you can import as follows:

1. You can disable the AUTO_INCREMENT on the new table as follows:
   ALTER TABLE [your_table] CHANGE `auto_increment_column_name` `auto_increment_column_name` INT(11) NOT NULL
2. After inserting, you can enable AUTO_INCREMENT  and set it again as follows:
   ALTER TABLE [your_table] AUTO_INCREMENT = [Maximum value]

Alternatively, you have to update all dependent tables foreign key values using a migration script.